# WSo2 ESB SSL certs

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying to get the WSo2 ESB to proxy over to a WSDL based service. The service is hosted in a remote server and the server requires mutual SSL handshake. It seems that the WSO2 esb is not able to present a certificate while renegotiating. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps given in the following blog post [1]

[1]http://www.soasecurity.org/2010/07/ssl-profiles-in-wso2-esb.html

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB has a file under repository/resources/security called client- truststore.jks. This file lists all the Certifying Authorities (CAs) that the ESB will recognise as valid when transacting over HTTPS with clients who have certificates verified by these CAs. Export service certificate and import it to "client- truststore.jks". I hope it help you.